# Convert a simple train/test into train/test over a batch

Tags: keras

I am using Recurrent NN to generate a classification model. The following is a simple RNN model that uses `keras` (Courtesy to this [blog](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/)):

```
tr_C, ts_C, tr_r, ts_r = train_test_split(C, r, train_size=.8)
tr_C = tr_C.reshape((tr_C.shape[0], tr_C.shape[1], 1))
ts_C = ts_C.reshape((ts_C.shape[0], ts_C.shape[1], 1))
tr_r = tr_r.reshape(tr_r.shape[0], 1)
ts_r = ts_r.reshape(ts_r.shape[0], 1)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16,
               batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1),
               activation='tanh',
               recurrent_activation='tanh',
               kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
               bias_initializer='he_uniform',
               # dropout=0.1,
               # recurrent_dropout=0.1,
               stateful=True,
               return_sequences=False,
               )
          )
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


for epoch in range(10):
    print ('epoch(%s): ' % epoch)
    mean_tr_acc = []
    mean_tr_loss = []
    for i in range(len(tr_C)):
        for j in range(max_len):
            tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(tr_C[i][j], axis=1), axis=1), tr_r[i])
            mean_tr_acc.append(tr_acc)
            mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
        model.reset_states()

    print('training_acc = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_acc)))
    print('loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss)))
    print('___________________________________')

    mean_te_acc = []
    mean_te_loss = []
    for i in range(len(ts_C)):
        for j in range(max_len):
            te_loss, te_acc = model.test_on_batch(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(ts_C[i][j], axis=1), axis=1), ts_r[i])
            mean_te_acc.append(te_acc)
            mean_te_loss.append(te_loss)
        model.reset_states()

        for j in range(max_len):
            y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(ts_C[i][j], axis=1), axis=1))
        model.reset_states()

    print('testing_acc = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_te_acc)))
    print('loss testing = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_te_loss)))
    print('___________________________________')
```

This is the summary of the model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (1, 16)                   1152      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 1)                    17        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,169
Trainable params: 1,169
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Instead of training a single sample at a time, can I modify this code to train a batch of samples? If so, how? Any suggestions are appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show us how the model is implemented? and even better, can you show us model.summary() ?

Comment: @DvirSamuel Right! I forgot to add that. Post is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared here:

```
model.add(LSTM(16,
               batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1),
               activation='tanh',
               recurrent_activation='tanh',
               kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
               bias_initializer='he_uniform',
               # dropout=0.1,
               # recurrent_dropout=0.1,
               stateful=True,
               return_sequences=False,
               )
          )
```

that the size of your batch should be: (1,1,1) meaning 1 example only, with 1 timestamp and each timestamp is scalar.
If you want more than 1 training example you should do:

```
batch_input_shape=(None,1,1)
```

or, change None to the number of examples in the batch.
(None means you can insert how many example as you wish)

Comment: I guess in this case the inner loop in `model.train_on_batch` has to be modified as well.

Comment: yess, you should make sure tha the input is the same shape as you stated in the lstm declaration :)